# Qt set iOS screen orientation

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qml

Working on a cross platform app in Qt.  I need to be able to force the screen orientation for a couple of pages.  I've found a way to do this for Android, but I can't find anything for iOS.

Is there any way to force set the screen orientation in iOS?

Better yet, is there a single call that will set the screen orientation for any given mobile platform?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html#orientation-attached-prop

You could write the Screen.orientation (or Screen.primaryOrientation) property into your own property and use the onChanged event handler to get a Signal, eg:

```
readonly property var screenOrientation: Screen.orientation

onScreenOrientationChanged: {
console.log("Orientation Changed!")
}
```